# Python: pandas Data Frame and meaning of {Series}0 in debugger

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, series

I am using pandas in Python 2.7 and read a csv file like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test_file.csv")
```

df has a column titled `rating`, and a column titled 'review', I do some manipulations on `df` for example:

```
df3 = df[df['rating'] != 3]
```

Now if I look in a debugger at `df['review']` and `df3['review']` I see this information:

```
df['review'] = {Series}0
df3['review'] = {Series}1
```

Also if I want to see the first element of `df['review']` I use:

```
df['review'][0]
```

which is fine, but if I do the same for `df3`, I get this error:

```
df3['review'][0]
{KeyError}0L
```

However, it looks like I can do this:

```
df3['review'][1]
```

Can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: Presumable because `0` is not a valid index value for `df3`? If you check the indices this may explain the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing with an integer on a Series doesn't work like a list. In particular, `df['review'][0]` doesn't get the first element of the "review" column, it gets the element with index 0:

```
In [4]: s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index=[1, 0, 2, 3])

In [5]: s
Out[5]:
1    a
0    b
2    c
3    d
dtype: object

In [6]: s[0]
Out[6]: 'b'
```

Presumably, in generating `df3` you dropped the row with index 0. If you actually want to get the first element regardless of the index, use `iloc`:

```
In [7]: s.iloc[0]
Out[7]: 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. Still you didn't answer my question on what is the meaning of {Series}0, and {Series}1. I up-voted you for helpful answer though.

Comment: If you're using PyCharm, you might just need to make your window bigger. I get something like this: `df['review'] = {Series}0    0\n1    1\n...`, where the first element of each line is the index, and the second is the value. I think you're seeing that the first index of df is 0 and the first index of df3 is 1.